# Calculating distance from point $(0,1)$ to a hypotenuse

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose we are looking to find distance from point $(0,1)$ to all other points on the hypotenuse you see below.

Formula to do that is as follows:

$$distance = 1 - \frac{\sqrt{(x)^2 + (y)^2}}{\sqrt{2}} \label{1}\tag{1}$$

I see if we substitute some points in the formula \ref{1} like when $(x=0, y=0)$ why we get distance = 1 from point $(0,1)$, but can you please add more intermediate steps how we derive such a formula?

[image]

Comment: The formula gives $d=0$ for $x=y=1$, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: @dxiv. Thank you.

Comment: The distance (I'm assuming green line) from $(0,1)$ to $(x,y)$ is $\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}$ regardless if $(x,y)$ lies on the hypotenuse.

Comment: @DavidP. It's $(y-1)$ inside square root because we have 1 in $(0,1)$ and another 1 when we are at point $(1,1)$ please?

Comment: It is derived from the pythagorean theorem. Draw a right triangle with the green line segment being your hypotenuse.